# 'related_name' works if create an object without saving?

Tags: django, orm

I have 2 django models related with a ForeignKey. So, I can create a parent object and different childs objects. I cannot save the objects, but I need get the 'related_name'. How I can do it?

```py
# create objects
parent = ParentModel(**serializer_in.validated_data)
child = ChildModel(**serializer_in.validated_data)

# relate objects
child.parent_field = parent

# try get childs
print(parent.child_set.all()) # is empty. why?
```

My related_name get an empty queryset. Why?

Comment: Hello and welcome  to stack overflow! Could you please share your model file that relates `ParentModel` and `ChildModel`?

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to save your `child` model after adding `parent_field` as below.

for an instance,

```
# create objects
parent = ParentModel(**serializer_in.validated_data)
child = ChildModel(**serializer_in.validated_data)

# relate objects
child.parent_field = parent
child.save() # Save your object

# try get childs
print(parent.child_set.all())
```

I hope this would work for you.

Comment: Hi Devang, 

I need don't save any object.

Thanks

Comment: But without persisting your model into database you would not get `parent.child_set.all()` with objects inside it.